# How can INSERT a JAVASCRIPT file to Odoo11.0 web builder?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-11

HOW CAN INSERT A JAVASCRIPT FILE TO ODOO 11.0 WEB BUILDER
I use Odoo 11.0 web builder for my website but I don't know how should insert a Javascript file to Odoo web builder such as CSS(Less)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <template id="assets_frontend" name="Website Form Assets Frontend" inherit_id="website.assets_frontend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">

                <script type="text/javascript" src="**yourmodule/static/src/js/file.js**"/>


            </xpath>
        </template>

    </data>
</odoo>
```